# LINQ - Output true/false "checklist" of items from list A contained in list B

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>(){ "a", "b", "c", "d"  };

List<string> list2 = new List<string>(){ "b", "d", "e" };
```

I want to find all items of list1 that match the items in list2, and generate a List list3 that contains:

```
{ false, true, false, true }
```

How can I go about that?

Thanks in advance,
Wavy

Answer (score 7):

This is all it takes:

```
list1.Select(str => list2.Contains(str)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Balazs answer is correct, but you should know that `Contains` operation on list is O(n) operation. And if lists are pretty big, then creating new list will be O(n*m) operation, which might be pretty slow. If you want to check whether some value is among other values, best way is having some hash-based structure which has O(1) for `Contains` operation. So, just put second list values to HashSet

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<string>(list2);
var result = list1.Select(hashSet.Contains).ToList();
```